# Use Material Design Components with ember-cli-sass

Tags: ember.js, sass, material-components-web

I'm trying to use Material Components Web(MDC-Web) sass functionality with ember-cli-sass.
I've installed MDC-Web with Yarn

In my ember-cli-build.js file I've set my sass includePaths as so:

```
 sassOptions: {
           includePaths: ['node_modules/material-components-web','node_modules/@material']      
    }
```

and then in my app.scss file attempted to import the full component library like so:

```
@import "material-components-web";
```

However I'm getting the error:

> Error: Error: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   @material/button/mdc-button.

Why is the SASS compiler not finding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got me as well the first time I was starting out. I've been using it in my [ember app](https://campus-discounts.com/) for a few months now and this is what works for me in my app.scss

```
// Parent MDC Theming example

$mdc-theme-primary: #009688;
$mdc-theme-secondary: #00bcd4;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;

@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";

// Overrides to follow example

.mdc-grid-tile__secondary{
    background-color: rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75);
}
.mdc-list-item{
    white-space: unset;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

And in ember-cli-build

```
sassOptions: {
  includePaths: [
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tried this in my project and it didn't work... so i tried it in a fresh project and it did.  I'll keep tinkering until I find out why! Thanks.

Comment: Ah I still had remnants of ember- material-components-web installed.  Removing them resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I am getting the CSS to work using this process but it seems that I am not getting the JS to function correctly.  Could you demonstrate how you achieve this in your component template file and components JS file?  Also you you have to do any app.import in the ember-cli.build.js?  Thanks!

Comment: @deanT Yes, I can show you, but kindly create a new question and paste the link here, since this one is specifically about sass, i.e the CSS part.

Comment: I posted a question about getting the JS to work here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058833/ember-js-how-to-import-material-components-web-js

Answer (score 0):

In ember you have to import dependencies, that are not ember addons, in `ember-cli.build.js`. See https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies. Since 2.15 it is also possible to import from node_modules (https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/import-javascripts-from-node-modules-packages/13606).

But in case of `material-components-web` this shouldn't be necessary at all. Instead you can simply use the ember addon [ember-material-components-web](https://github.com/secondstreet/ember-material-components-web)
 that includes `material-components-web` for you.

Comment: Thanks - however the  ember-material-components-web had too many issues for me (it's incomplete for a start with little support) - hence why I'm trying to import MDC directly.

My question isn't about importing the javascript - it's about importing the SCSS - so I don't think the links you've provided are useful.

Comment: ember-material-components-web also imports the CSS directly I believe rather than allowing access to the SASS Mixins - which is what I need.

Comment: The given links also explains import of other assets then JavaScript. You can also import CSS/SCSS  with app.import.

Comment: The managing dependencies link tells you to use ember-cli-sass to import SASS - which is what my question is about.  I can't see anything that states you can app.import scss files?