# emberjs -ember-cli-chart extend doughnut chart to create rounded edge

Tags: ember.js, chart.js, ember-cli

how do i extend chart object in ember-cli-cart ?? i want to extend dooughnut to have smooth edges and some other features too. something like the below code ,but i want to create as a reusable ember component

```
 Chart.types.doughnut.extend({
        draw: function (ease) {
                var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;

            var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
            Chart.helpers.each(this.getDataset().metaData, function (arc, index) {
                arc.transition(easingDecimal).draw();

                var vm = arc._view;
                var radius = (vm.outerRadius + vm.innerRadius) / 2;
                var thickness = (vm.outerRadius - vm.innerRadius) / 2;
                var angle = Math.PI - vm.endAngle - Math.PI / 2;

                ctx.save();
                ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
                ctx.translate(vm.x, vm.y);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(radius * Math.sin(angle), radius * Math.cos(angle), thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.arc(radius * Math.sin(Math.PI), radius * Math.cos(Math.PI), thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.restore();
            });
        },
    });
```

Comment: I haven't used ember-cli-cart but if you use Chart.js directly then it's a piece of cake, very similar to the advise I gave in this answer for how to integrate material components web in ember js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083865/use-material-design-components-with-ember-cli-sass/48087403#48087403