# Ember JS: How to import Material Components Web JS

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use Material Components Web(MDC-Web) with an EmberJS application. I've installed `material-components-web` with Yarn.

```
yarn add material-components-web --dev
```

This installed material-components-web@0.41.0.

I have the sass/CSS working but can't figure out how to include/import the JS.  Could someone show me how it would import that into my component js file and/or my component template file.

I get an `no file error` when I do an

```
app.import('node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please add the version of material-components-web that you've installed?

Comment: What versions of Ember and Ember CLI are you using in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I normally use Material Components Web in my [Ember project](https://campus-discounts.com/). Has worked for me since Ember version 2.x upto the latest 3.x.

First in ember-cli-build.js. Import the required js file

```
  app.import('node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js', {
    using: [{
      transformation: 'fastbootShim'
    }]
  });
```

The using part is only applicable if you use Fastboot (which you should) so as to exclude the file from executing in a Fastboot environment.

Then fear not, in an Ember component on the didInsertElement hook, activate the MDC component for example for a modal drawer component I have used code like this.

```
  tagName: 'aside',
  classNames: ['mdc-drawer', 'mdc-drawer--modal', 'app-drawer'],

  didInsertElement: function () {
    let component = this;

    let componentJqueryObject = component.$();
    let componentElement = componentJqueryObject[0];

    let MDCDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer;
    let drawer = new MDCDrawer(componentElement);

    $('header').on('click', '.drawer-menu', function() {
      drawer.open = !drawer.open;
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'main', function() {
      drawer.open = false;
    });

    $('aside').on('click', 'a', function() {
      drawer.open = false;
    });
..........
```

For a MDC top-app-bar component (latest MDC only) I've used this

```
  tagName: 'header',
  classNames: ['mdc-top-app-bar', 'mdc-top-app-bar--fixed'],

  didInsertElement: function () {
    let component = this;

    let componentJqueryObject = component.$();
    let componentElement = componentJqueryObject[0];

    let topAppBar = new mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar(componentElement);
    let mainEl = document.getElementById('app-main');
    topAppBar.setScrollTarget(mainEl);
```

............

Note: Its important to always use the didInsertHook for 2 reasons.
1.) According to Ember Docs, didInsert is at that point where the component's HTML is guaranteed to be inserted in the DOM.
2.) According to Fastboot Docs, didInsert is not executed in FastBoot mode which runs in Node yet MDC is a browser thing.

Enjoy!

EDIT: Based on Question below

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { get } from '@ember/object';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'aside',
  classNames: ['mdc-drawer', 'mdc-drawer--modal', 'app-drawer'],

  didInsertElement: function () {
    let component = this;

    let componentJqueryObject = component.$();
    let componentElement = componentJqueryObject[0];

    let MDCDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer;
    let drawer = new MDCDrawer(componentElement);

    $('header').on('click', '.drawer-menu', function() {
      drawer.open = !drawer.open;
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'main', function() {
      drawer.open = false;
    });

    $('aside').on('click', 'a', function() {
      drawer.open = false;
    });

    // mdc web used to override the a href link element in the drawer component, causing all links to open with a page reload, use this hack if your version still does, assign every a href link a custom-link class and add data attributes to keep things the Ember way

    let router = get(component, "router");

    component.$().on("click" , ".custom-link" , function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      drawer.open = false;

      let routeName = $(this).data("route");
      let modelId = $(this).data("id");

      if(modelId){
        router.transitionTo(routeName , modelId);
      } else {
        router.transitionTo(routeName);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am still getting errors, I believe the are related to missing imports in the component JS file.  Can you share the import statements on the top of your posted files?  I assume you have: import Component from '@ember/component'; and I am guessing something related to the mdc components.... Thanks

Comment: This is no MDC component that you have to import, your whole ember project will be simple if you keep it so. I've shared a real live example I've used for 2 years now.

Comment: Still struggling with this...  I created a project here: https://bitbucket.org/deantomlinson/mcwtest/src/master/ so that all the code would be available.  The styling for the text input looks correct but the JS for the floating label doesn't seem to work.  Also get errors for the variables in the x-input.js not being used.

Comment: Great, I've taken a look and sent in a PR, please see the changes, main issue is missing capital F in let MDCTextField = mdc.textField.MDCTextField;
Though also did a little clean up, importing the Router is not necessary, I only did so for the drawer component because mdc web used to override it.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for helping me with that Don!