# Why can't I set persistence even though login functions work with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js, import, firebase-authentication

I have a component with a form that holds the email and password. Imports at the top:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Next, I inject the service for the firebaseApp and session (session just has some attrs that I set to tell the app we're authenticated -- these will be refactored later):

```
session: service(),
firebaseApp: service(),
```

If I pass these values into the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` function from `fbApp.auth()`, the account is validated and logged in. Works as expected:

```
login() {
  const session = this.get('session');
  const fbApp = this.get('firebaseApp');
  const e = this.get('form.email');
  const p = this.get('form.password');

  fbApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p).then(u => {
    session.set('user.email', u.email);
    session.set('user.signedIn', true);
    this.get('goHome')(); // route transition to home
  }).catch(e => {
    this.set('error', 'Something went wrong. Try again?');
  });
}
```

Next, I wanted to persist the session so that the user is not logged out on refresh, only if the tab is closed. So I modified the code and wrapped the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` in with `setPersistence` as follows:

```
login() {
  const session = this.get('session');
  const fbApp = this.get('firebaseApp');
  const e = this.get('form.email');
  const p = this.get('form.password');

  fbApp.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
              .then(()=> {

    fbApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p).then(u => {
      session.set('user.email', u.email);
      session.set('user.signedIn', true);
      this.get('goHome')(); // route transition to home
    }).catch(e => {
      this.set('error', 'Something went wrong. Try again?');
    });

  }).catch(e => {
    this.set('error', 'Something went wrong. Try again?');
  });
}
```

This doesn't work. I get a `Cannot read property 'SESSION' of undefined` error in the console. I'm sure it has to do with how firebase is imported but I'm having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to the one I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058833/ember-js-how-to-import-material-components-web-js/53064194) on how to import Material Components Web JavaScript file.

Luckily, I been using Firebase and Firebase Auth in my Ambitious [EmberJS project](https://campus-discounts.com/) for about a year now. The process is dead simple, complete working example below.

In package.json

```
....
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
....
```

In ember-cli-build.js

```
....
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    ....
    fingerprint: {
      enabled: true,
      generateAssetMap: true,
      exclude: [
        'firebase-app',
        'firebase-auth',
        'firebase-messaging',
        'firebase-messaging-sw',
        ....
      ]
    },
    ....
  });

  ....

  app.import('node_modules/firebase/firebase-app.js', { outputFile: 'firebase-app.js'});
  app.import('node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth.js', { outputFile: 'firebase-auth.js'});
  app.import('node_modules/firebase/firebase-messaging.js', { outputFile: 'firebase-messaging.js'});
....
```

In index.html **before** vendor.js and app.js files

```
....
    <script src="/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "ABC123XYZ",
        authDomain: "auth.my-app.com", // Did you know you can customize this or use default my-app.firebaseapp.com
        databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "my-app",
        storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "123456789"
      };
      if( typeof firebase !== 'undefined'  && firebase) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
      }
    </script>
....
```

In .eslintrc.js

```
....
module.exports = {
  ....
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  globals: {
    "firebase": false
  },
  ....
};
....
```

Then anywhere **but not** in Fastboot (if using it) just called firebase methods and properties.e.g

```
....
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdTokenResult()
          .then((idTokenResult) => {
            session.setToken(idTokenResult.token);
            if (idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
              session.setIsAdmin(true);
            } else {
              session.setIsAdmin(false);
            }

            session.setUser(user);

            session.setIsAuthenticated(true);

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        // ...
      }
    });
....
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This certainly does work. Thank you Don. Just to be clear if you want database, etc. you would have to import those as well.

Also, the emberfire adapter I was using is just slow to be updated and I want to use firestone sooner rather than later so I removed ember-data completely.

Comment: You are welcome :) and you are correct as well, any other features need to have their files imported as well, like database, storage, etc. I'm also a big fan of directly integrating scripts whenever I can, rather than relying on 3rd parties. I appreciate their work, but a good mix is healthy.